# Ubuntu Touch - Shutdown sometimes rebooting phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, shutdown

Since the last Ubuntu update on the 02.06, I have noticed that on a few occasions, that when I shutdown my phone it will reboot itself straight away. I shut the phone down by clicking on the Notification Panel at the top, selecting System > Shutdown and then Power Off. Here I am pressing Shutdown and not Restart. Is there a setting that I can adjust or turn on/off to ensure that the phone does not reboot when I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

I know about this bug. This often happens with me, when I had a long session with my phone and especially when there were many progress with the Unity 8 gui e.g. switching between staged and windowed mode. In these cases the display server seems to work optically properly, but for real it runs laggy. You sometimes reconize it by failing updates and installations. When you press shutdown, not your phablet reboots (there's not the initial bootscreen) but just the display server (lightdm). But the error persist. My only known possibility getting out of this loop is a hard power off by pressing the on button about ten seconds or so. I also hope this bug will be removed in the future.

Hope I can 'help' you.

Comment: Thank you for yoyr comments, it is good to hear that I am not the only person having this issue. As this rules out hardware problems. I have also on occasion had to do the hard reboot for about 10 to 15 seconds. I think I will have to raise this in Launchpad.

Comment: This has happened to me about three times. I just thought that I may of pressed reboot by mistake, but thinking back it was shutdown.

Comment: I think you should really raise a bug at launchpad! And please don't forget to post a bug-link here.

Comment: As yet, I have not raised the bug for this. However it is still occurring.

Comment: I have now raised this bug in Launchpad, the number is https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1597194